# Any $2$-Sylow subgroup of $S_6$ is isomorphic to the group $D_{2(4)}\times Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that any $2-Sylow$ subgroup of $S_6$ is isomorphic to the group  $D_{2(4)}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

This is how I proceeded:

Consider $D_{2(4)}$ as permutation of $1-4$ fixing $5$ and $6$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $S_6$  which fixes $5$ and $6$. Then is $H \cong D_{2(4)}$. Next I considered $ \tau =(5,6)$ then $K=<\tau>$ is a subgroup and $K \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. So we have $HK=KH$ as $H\cap K=\{e\}$.  How do I show that $HK \le G$? Then if I show this we will have  $H \times K \cong 2-Sylow$ subgroup of $S_6$.

Comment: I never saw the notation $D_{2(4)}$, can you explain what it means and what is in general $D_{m(n)}$? At first I thought you mean the dihedral group on 4 elements that by some sources is written $D_2$ and by others $D_4$ and this a way to clarify which dehedral group is meant; (so an even easier way would be to write $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$) but then the statement $H \cong D_{2(4)}$ shows that $D_{2(4)}$ must be isomorphic to $S_4$ and hence has 24 rather than 4 elements. But then again, the group of all elements fixing 5 and 6 is not 2-sylow, so perhaps I misread the def. of $H$?

Comment: I think he means the symmetries on a square

Answer (score 1):

$K$ normalizes $H$, because cycle decompositions of elements of $K$ and $H$ do not overlap (e.g. $(56)(1324)(56)^{-1} = (1324))$. So $K \subset N_G(H)$, hence $HK \le G$

Proving that $K \subset N_G(H) => HK \le G$:

$k \in K, h \in H$. $khk^{-1} \in H$, so $kh = khk^{-1} = h_1k \in HK$, hence $KH \subset HK$. Next $hk = kk^{-1}hk = kh_1 \in KH$, hence $HK \subset KH$. Therefore $HK = KH$.

Edit: or your question was how to prove $HK = KH => HK \le G$?

Then, let $HK = KH, x, y \in HK, x = h_1k_1, y = h_2K_2.$ We are going to prove that $xy^{-1} \in HK$.

$xy^{-1} = h_1k_1k^{-1}_2h^{-1}_2 = h_1(k_3h^{-1}_2) = h_1h_4k_4 \in HK.$ Hence $HK \le G$.